# How to create a SSL expire Alert for a website

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have a scenario where I have to create a SSL Check alert for some websites, I have created an uptime alert for one of them and it the same have enabled SSL Certificate Validation over there, and I have a policy setup on it for 15day alert before expire and 7days and 1 day.

Every-time I try to test it, it gives me "Responded with "403 (Forbidden)" in 983 ms."
How can I use the ssl check alert service of Google cloud Monitoring, I just want an alert to make me aware about the expire of my website certificates.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkW0I.png)